# Getting elements of other UITableViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

There is a question: 
i have two UITableViewController: FirstController, SecondController. How do i get accesoryType for each cell from FirstController in SecondController?

Comment: I would suggest reconsidering your design. How does your first table view know what accessoryType belongs in the cell? I would hope that it is gathering that information from the model. If so, then the second table view should only have to query the model for the first tableview to determine the accessory type.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like: [

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
cell = [UITableViewCell ....
....
[cell accessoryView];
return cell;

}
```

You might take a look at: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html hope that helps.

Comment: i already created table with cells in FirstController, but now, in SecondController i need to get amount of cells from FirstController, that's accesoryType is UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark.

Comment: Hmmm not sure how I would that since normally I wouldn't. I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish but you could creat a property on SecondViewController called parent or something like that and set it to the firstViewController, so you could call [fvc tableView] and possibly loop through the cells. If this sounds like a bad idea that's because it is. I would take a look at your business logic and find a better way to pass the data between the class; maybe a custom init?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you want to (kind of) copy the table from the FirstVC to the SecondVC - or at least the accessoryTypes of each cell. A weak parent property in the SecondVC is how I would do it - though, admittedly, I know no other way.

Then, in the SecondVC's `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you would say something like `cell.accessoryType = [parent.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType;`. That should set the SecondVC's cell.accessoryType to the parent's cell.accessoryType in the same indexPath.

Answer (score 0):

Just write the amount of Cells in dummy NSInteger object and access it in your 2nd TVC. If they are both loaded and added by the same Controller its totally easy because you can handle it with properties, if not, handle them with a custom delegate.